# Mapping New Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is my data.

```
{
    "contacts": "ners.com",
    "recipient": "krtners.com",
    "date_sent": "07/07/2020 21:35:31",
    "subject": "Re: David vs Goliath -"
}
```

And I'm trying to use `getTime` function and it keeps returning `NaN`.

```js
const timeStamp = (old_date) => {
        let now = new Date(old_date);
        console.log(old_date);
        now = now.getTime();
        return now;
      };

data.map((i) => (i.date_sent = timeStamp(date_sent)));
```

Comment: what format do you expect the date output to be in. and when you console long now instead of old_date at the same line, what do you get?

Comment: Looking at your code. It should work but if it's not working there has to be something wrong with the data_sent variable down in the lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this? Can't get what you trying to achieve... Check code below, read comments, test it by pressing "Run code snippet"

```js
data = [{
  "contacts": "giovani@energyimpactpartners.com",
  "recipient": "kann@energyimpactpartners.com",
  "date_sent": "07/07/2020 21:25:31",
  "subject": "Re: David1 vs Goliath1 -"
},{
  "contacts": "giovani@energyimpactpartners.com",
  "recipient": "kann@energyimpactpartners.com",
  "date_sent": "07/07/2020 21:35:31",
  "subject": "Re: David2 vs Goliath2 -"
},{
  "contacts": "giovani@energyimpactpartners.com",
  "recipient": "kann@energyimpactpartners.com",
  "date_sent": "07/07/2020 21:45:31",
  "subject": "Re: David3 vs Goliath3 -"
}];

const timeStamp = (old_date) => {
  let now = new Date(old_date);
  now = now.getTime();
  return now;
};

// Extend data with timeStamp field
data.map((i) => i.date_sent = timeStamp(i.date_sent));

// Log
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks bro for the tip but what im tryng is replacing the return value of the "date_sent" to "timeStamp" into my list.  Thanks btw bro

Comment: @WaBroqueza ok, I've updated my answer, now value of `date_sent` is replaced by timestamp